# Does it require eveyone to have a gmail account to run a colab notebook?

Tags: google-colaboratory

We are planning a lecture series of machine learning and is trying to show some easy examples using Google Colab. However, some of the target audience is not that familiar computer or programming stuff, and we want to make it as easy as possible.

I'm wondering is it a must for everyone to have a Gmail account to view the examples in Colab? Or is there anything similar to using a 'group access' that we can set up a guest account?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Users can view notebooks shared publicly without sign-in.

In order to execute code, a Google account sign-in is required. Instructions to create an account [are here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27441?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in 2023 it is necessary to have a Google account. Just sharing the link is not working anymore. Because I had this issue I moved to [binder](https://ovh2.mybinder.org). The setup is more difficult since all is backed by a public GitHub page and hence works only with public data.